# I want to flip an icon from the topbar of a website

Tags: html, css

I have this website: https://www.luxit.com.au/. I want to flip the phone icons from the top bar.

I inspected the page and use the class but that is not working. Then I notice that this is a sub-class, that is mentioned with i and then class and then on the last again i.

Can someone help me to find or how to write this type of class correctly in custom CSS. Thank you

Comment: what does this have to do with js, python and jquery and probably html?

Comment: Please may you include a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: You can target the phone with `#top-bar #top-bar-content .fa.fa-phone { ... }` . By using more parent id's the priority will be stronger then other css that is used in your stylesheet.

Comment: You are one of the very rare geniuses in this world. I used your above method and that's really worked for me. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change

`fa-phone`

to

`fa-phone-alt`

in the `i` tag for the icons you want to flip.

e.g. instead of

`<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>`

change it to

`<i class="fa fa-phone-alt"></i>`

These are Font Awesome icons, see here https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=phone

Comment: Is tag necessary to include when we do custom CSS?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: .fa-phone-alt{transform: rotateY(180deg);}

Comment: sorry to say but this is also not working

Comment: It worked a second ago, did you add css for `.fa-phone-alt` to rotate it? if you remove that, the alt icon will work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. Can you please simply tell me the right class and i will fill my custom CSS needs in it. That will work for me. Example: .alt{      } in this way.

Comment: Yes i added my css in .fa-phon-alt

Comment: You shouldn't need any custom css, but you can do it the way you wanted, but use `fa-phone` instead of `fa-phone-alt`, as by doing that, you are using the inverted icon, and inverting it again using css, so it looks the same as what you started with, so either use the css on the original phone icon, or use the flipped phone icon and no custom css.

Comment: Believe me that I know some of the codings in CSS and HTML, I am a WordPress developer but there is no option to change the icon directly so that,s why I was here seeking help to flip the icon. However here is the shortcode that i found href="tel:037866889783">372889887892</a></span><span class="mobile-clr"><span> I don't know how i can replace the earlier icon with the new one that is already flipped.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have looked at the relevant code, one good trick is to copy it (Edit HTML and copy it in your devtools) and lay it out properly so you can see what is nested in what.

This is the code in the area you are interested in:

```
<span class="topbar-content">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
&nbsp;
  <span>
    <a href="tel:1300724555">1300 724 555</a> </span>
  <span> | </span>
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <span>
    <a href="tel:0452611880">0452 611 880</a>
  </span>
  <span class="mobile-clr">
    <span>&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
  <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
  &nbsp;
  <span>7am - 10pm, 7 days </span>
  <span class="mobile-clr">
   <span>&nbsp;</span>
 </span>
</span>
```

I am not clear whether you want to get rid of the lot, in which case:

```
.topbar-content { visibility: hidden; }
```

(do this instead of display: none in case some other spacing/positioning is relying on it)

or whether you want to get rid of just one phone number in which case you could start to use nth-of-type but it depends which one you want to get rid of. Let me know if that's the case.